# SQL store the join result into a new database table

Tags: c#, sql

This is my SQL query that use join to merge two table on SQL database, therefore I would like to sent the result to newly created database, `SAP_Mat_StoreBGA_test`.

However, my query is not working, please help.

```
foreach (DataRow row2 in dt1.Rows)
{
    query4 = "SELECT * FROM SAP_Mat_StoreBGA BGA LEFT JOIN SAP_Mes_BuildPlan ON SAP_Mes_BuildPlan.SMT_Assembly = BGA.Component WHERE BGA.Component like '73%'" 
             + "INSERT INTO SAP_Mat_StoreBGA_test (BGA.Material, BGA.Component, SMT_Assembly) VALUES('" + row2["BGA.Material"]+ "','" + row2["BGA.Component"] + "','" + row2["SMT_Assembly"] + "')";

    CheckingCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: And also: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an insert-select

```
INSERT INTO SAP_Mat_StoreBGA_test (BGA.Material, BGA.Component, SMT_Assembly)
SELECT BGA.Material, BGA.Component, SMT_Assembly FROM SAP_Mat_StoreBGA BGA 
LEFT JOIN SAP_Mes_BuildPlan ON SAP_Mes_BuildPlan.SMT_Assembly = BGA.Component
WHERE BGA.Component like '73%'
```